Preventing Checkout if postcode out of area in WooCommerce
We have installed & tweaked the following widget that checks to see if postcodes are in our delivery areas, if not it auto redirects them to a page to register their interest.
<div id="deliverychecker-container" data-widget-id="166f5152dc8d7b"></div>
<script>
(function() {
    const i = setInterval(function() {
        const d = document.getElementById("deliverychecker-results");
        if (!d) {
            return;
        }
        const t = d.firstChild.firstChild.innerText.slice(0, 5);
        if (t == "Sorry") {
            clearInterval(i);
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "/register-your-interest-261/";
            }, 3000)
        };
    }, 1000);
    var a = document.createElement("script");
    a.type = "text/javascript";
    a.async = !0;
    a.src = "https://cdn.deliverychecker.co/api/v1/js/166f5152dc8d7b.js";
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}());
</script>

The API calls an external db that has the postcodes in (a subset of PAF)
I now need to do the same thing on the WooCommerce chekout page to prevent people adding a different postcode that is out of area, but I can't work out how to do so.
Note that we are using WooCommerce classic checkout (shortcode).
Any pointers please, I am stuck as to where to start.

To prevent customers from completing a checkout in WooCommerce,  idea is to hook into WooCommerce's checkout validation system and stop the checkout process if the postcode is out of your delivery area.
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_postcode_before_checkout');

function validate_postcode_before_checkout($posted) {
    // Get the billing postcode from the checkout form
    $postcode = isset($posted['billing_postcode']) ? $posted['billing_postcode'] : '';
    
    // Call the Delivery Checker API to verify if the postcode is in the delivery area
    $response = wp_remote_get("https://cdn.deliverychecker.co/api/v1/check-postcode?postcode=" . urlencode($postcode) . "&widget-id=166f5152dc8d7b");

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Could not verify your postcode. Please try again later.'), 'error');
        return;
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    // Check the response for a valid delivery area
    if (isset($data['status']) && $data['status'] === 'error') {
        wc_add_notice(__('Sorry, we do not deliver to your postcode.'), 'error');
    }
}

I hope, this will work for you.

Thanks for the response - we will give this a try

Apologies for the seemingly daft question but am learning - I assume I can paste this on the checkout page?

No, you need to add this at the end of function.php file

Tried this by adding to the end of the function.php file - sadly it still allowed an order to be completed
